# get the quotient used in a division in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have cells in a GoogleSheet table, in those cells I introduced a division between 2 numbers (example:  =48,775/1,1839. See image). I would like to get the quotient of this operation. In the case of the example it would be 1,1839. Can anybody help me with that?

[image]

Comment: A nitpick, but you want the *denominator*. The quotient is the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

To get formula as text use `FORMULATEXT`. Then if you want get number use `INDEX`/`SPLIT`:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FORMULATEXT(A1),"/"),1,2)
```

if you want text use REGEXTRACT:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(FORMULATEXT(A1),".+\/(.+)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used directly in sheets:

```
=RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(G2),len(FORMULATEXT(G2))-(find("/",FORMULATEXT(G2))))
```